# How to find how many hours an Android phone has been used in total (regardless of factory reset)?

Tags: screen, clock

I want to know if there is a method or application that can tell me how many hours an Android phone has been used. Just like we have cheat codes that we used for Nokia phones; they tell us the hours (regardless of factory reset). Any alternate for Android?